# Getting Uncaught TypeError with Jquery rateIt plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, rateit.js

I am using Jquery rateIt plugin in my backbone project.

I am using its AJAX example part .

I could see images are loading no call going through and no response and some time get error like

**"Uncaught TypeError: Object rateAnswer has no method 'apply' "**

here is my JS

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!tpl/questionnaire.html', 'Collection/cAppCollection', 'Models/mAppModel', 'jqueryRateIt'], 
function($, _, Backbone, questionnaireTpl, appCollection, appModel, jqRateIt) {

var questionnaire = Backbone.View.extend({

    el : '.row',
    template : _.template(questionnaireTpl),

    initialize : function(e) {

        $('.hero-unit').css('display','none');
        this.render(e);
    },
    //this renders my template 
    //on success of response , loads response than call rateit() function than bind rated and reset to function rateAnswer
    //but here no call fo rateAnswer
    render : function(e) {

            var elem = this.$el,
                temp = this.template,
                appCollectObj = new appCollection();

                appCollectObj.fetch({
                    data: $.param({subject: e.id}),
                    success: function(model, response) {
                            $(elem).html(temp({model:response}));
                             $('div.rateit').rateit();
                             $('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', 'rateAnswer');
                            },
                    error: function() {
                            console.log('Failed to fetch!');
                            }
                });

    },

    rateAnswer : function(){

                var ri = $(this),
                appCollectObj = new appCollection();


                var value = ri.rateit('value');
                var questionId = ri.data('productid'); 

                appCollectObj.fetch({
                    data: $.param({questionId : questionId, value : value}),
                    success: function(model, response) {
                            $('#response').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
                            },
                    error: function() {
                            $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                            }
                });
    }
  });

  return questionnaire;
});
```

and HTML part is

```
<div id="products">
        <ul>
          <li>
           RateIt: <div data-productid="<%= elem.id %>" class="rateit"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="response"></ul>
      </div>
```

[here the link to RateIt plugin example](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm#ex_11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is typical of an event binding incorrectly done... (trying to call apply on something that isn't a function).

```
$('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', 'rateAnswer');
```

I have never seen this syntax, where did you see in the documentation that you can give a string instead of the function parameter?

Here you want to bind to a function that is outside of your callback, so before the appCollectObj.fetch, add something like:

```
var thisView = this;
```

Then it should probably be:

```
$('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', thisView.rateAnswer);
```

And you'll probably have issues because this in the event handler won't be working as you expect...so you can wrap your rateAnswer with $.proxy (or _.bindAll from _.underscore...):

```
$('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', $.proxy(thisView.rateAnswer, thisView));
```

Comment: tried $.proxy(this.rateAnswer, this) as well as $.proxy(this.rateAnswer, this) still no call to function rateAnswer

Comment: $('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', 'rateAnswer'); here passing string instead of function was my bad thanks for the correction. Now i have no error but no call for bind function

Comment: Ah my bad, I do too much coffeescript (and its beautiful fat arrow). You are already in a callback, so 'this' is already 'wrong'. I have edited my answer.